# java date difference puzzle

Tags: java, time

I am trying to calculate a date time difference but I'm getting some strange results:
Here is the source:

```
   import java.util.Calendar;
    import java.util.Collections;
    import java.util.Vector;

    public class Main {

        static Calendar dcal = Calendar.getInstance();
    static Calendar ccal = Calendar.getInstance();
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        dcal.set(2011, 1, 27);
        ccal.set(2011,2,1);
        long dtime = dcal.getTimeInMillis();
        long ctime = ccal.getTimeInMillis();
        long diff = ctime - dtime;
        int hours = (int) (diff / (1000 * 60 * 60));
        System.out.println("hours->"+hours);

    }

}
```

When I set ccal to 1 31 2011 the date difference is 96 hours but when I set it to 2 1 2011
the date difference is 48 hours.     How can this be?   What is the remedy?

Thanks,

Elliott

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you're setting ccal like so "`ccal.set(2011, 1, 31)`" the date is actually March 3, 2001, since months are zero based and the calendar rolls by default.  So the difference of 48hrs (96-48) is correct because there are two days between March 1 (`set(2011,2,1)`) and March 3 (`set(2011,1,31)`).

Comment: Thanks for the info on the Calendar rolling by default.

Answer (score 4):

You know that months are 0 based, right?  So that 0 represents January and 1 represents February, so that 1 31 2011 doesn't exist.  In fact it is better not to use numbers at all but instead to use the Calendar constants for the months, i.e.: Calendar.JANUARY.  To see for yourself what's happening, print out your Calendar's respective Date:

```
  ccal.set(2011, 1, 31);
  System.out.println(ccal.getTime());
```

Comment: I do know that but it does not explain the result

Comment: I think that it does.  Since 1 31 2011 doesn't exist, unexpected things happen.  Again, print out the Date as I mentioned in my answer's edit.

Comment: No, not unexpected. Perfectly well documented.

Comment: Thanks. Yep, I'm finding this out.